# Tips for using BeautifulSoup or other Python packages to web scrape tables from pop-up windows?

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

https://www.bls.gov/charts/consumer-price-index/consumer-price-index-by-region.htm

I want to web scrape this table of CPI changes from the US BLS, but I'm not sure how to do it since it is a pop up. You can see it if you click "Show table". (And I don't see a link to just download the table.) Is it possible to do this with BeautifulSoup?

I've tried inspecting the page but I can't figure out how to access the HTML for this table.

Answer (score 2):

Try [`pandas.read_html()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/dev/reference/api/pandas.read_html.html#pandas-read-html):

```py
import requests
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://www.bls.gov/charts/consumer-price-index/consumer-price-index-by-region.htm'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/112.0'}
df = pd.read_html(requests.get(url, headers=headers).text)[0]

print(df.head())
```

Prints:

```
       Month South  West Midwest Northeast South Atlantic Mountain East North Central New England East South Central Pacific West North Central Middle Atlantic West South Central
0   Mar 2003  3.1%  2.9%    2.9%      3.2%            NaN      NaN                NaN         NaN                NaN     NaN                NaN             NaN                NaN
1   Apr 2003  2.5%  2.0%    1.8%      2.6%            NaN      NaN                NaN         NaN                NaN     NaN                NaN             NaN                NaN
2   May 2003  2.1%  2.0%    1.7%      2.7%            NaN      NaN                NaN         NaN                NaN     NaN                NaN             NaN                NaN
3  June 2003  2.1%  2.0%    1.8%      2.7%            NaN      NaN                NaN         NaN                NaN     NaN                NaN             NaN                NaN
4  July 2003  2.1%  2.0%    1.6%      2.8%            NaN      NaN                NaN         NaN                NaN     NaN                NaN             NaN                NaN
```